# .Net 5 Api System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported

Tags: azure-web-app-service, .net-5, system.text.json

I have .net 5 api which works on my machine but not on Azure App Service. It looks like its failing to write the response and following is the Exception stack trace and Startup code. I am using System.Text.Json.
I am not sure whats causing this hence the question. I can see the controller action gets executed so deserialization works fine on the way in. It fails when writing response.

Specifically, it errors on calling move next in a custom middleware which calls Authentication middleware as seen in Stacktrace.

```
CheckRequestHeaderMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext
```

Controller action method :

```
 try
            {
                request.IdFromToken = GetIdFromToken();

                if (!await IsValidAsync(request, _requestValidator))
                {  
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);                    
                }
                if (!Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("X-ClientId"))
                {   
                    return BadRequest("Header X-ClientId is missing");
                }
                else
                {
                    request.ClientId = Guid.Parse(Request.Headers["X-ClientId"]);
                }
                // Encoding to prevent xss attack
                xssValidation.xssHtmlEncoding(request);               
                var serializedMessage = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
                await _messagePublisher.SendAsync(serializedMessage);

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (BadRequestException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,ex);
            }
```

```
System.NotSupportedException:
  at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer+<WriteAsyncCore>d__42`1.MoveNext (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter+<WriteResponseBodyAsync>d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|21_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0>d`2.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1+<ProcessRequestAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
Inner exception System.NotSupportedException handled at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException:
  at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.TypeConverter.Write (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
  at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore (System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            //-------------------- Code below is for configuring rate limitter ------------------------------------

            // needed to load configuration from appsettings.json
            services.AddOptions();
            // needed to store rate limit counters and ip rules
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            //load general configuration from appsettings.json
            services.Configure<ClientRateLimitOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ClientRateLimiting"));
            //load client rules from appsettings.json
            services.Configure<ClientRateLimitPolicies>(Configuration.GetSection("ClientRateLimitPolicies"));
            // inject counter and rules stores
            services.AddSingleton<IClientPolicyStore, MemoryCacheClientPolicyStore>();
            services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();

            var clientRateLimitPolicies = new ClientRateLimitPolicies();
            Configuration.GetSection("ClientRateLimitPolicies").Bind(clientRateLimitPolicies);

            var clientRateLimitOptions = new ClientRateLimitOptions();
            Configuration.GetSection("ClientRateLimitPolicies").Bind(clientRateLimitOptions);
            // https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793
            // the IHttpContextAccessor service is not registered by default.
            // the clientId/clientIp resolvers use it.
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            // configuration (resolvers, counter key builders)
            services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();

            //-------------------- End of rate limiting config  ------------------------------------

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options)).AddJwtBearer(options=> { options.SaveToken = true; });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);           


            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Test" });
                c.OperationFilter<ExamplesOperationFilter>();
            });
            services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
            services.Configure<ApplicationConfigItems>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationConfigItems"));
            DIConfig.Register(services);
            DataLayerDIConfig.ConnectionString = DIConfig.ServiceProvider.GetService<IOptionsSnapshot<ConnectionStrings>>();
            services.AddRevalAPIDataService();
            services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
                c.AddPolicy("AllowHeaders", options => options.AllowAnyHeader());
                c.AddPolicy("AllowMethod", options => options.AllowAnyMethod());
            });
            services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, RequestBodyInitializer>();
        }



        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            //app.UseClientRateLimiting();
            app.UseRequestHeaderMiddleware();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
            if (SwaggerHelper.ShouldEnableSwagger())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test"));
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I guess your response object contains a field of type `System.Type` somewhere?

Comment: It just returns standard Ok() response. I have updated the question with controller action code as well.

Comment: Your problem is here: when you do `return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,ex);` you are trying to return a `System.Exception` -- which will need to be serialized by System.Text.Json.  Unfortunately, System.Text.Json does not support serialization of exceptions.  See [Why does System.Text.Json throw a `NotSupportedException` for `System.IntPtr` when I'm not using `System.IntPtr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71143140/3744182), which looks to be an exact duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does System.Text.Json throw a \`NotSupportedException\` for \`System.IntPtr\` when I'm not using \`System.IntPtr\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71132371/why-does-system-text-json-throw-a-notsupportedexception-for-system-intptr-wh)