# Exception is not deserialized correctly from string when using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a custom exception:

```
[Serializable]
public class InternalException : Exception, ISerializable
{ 
    public InternalException() 
        : base()    
    { }

    public InternalException(string message)
        : base(message)
    { }

    public InternalException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    { }

    protected InternalException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {  }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}
```

I am doing this so that I can wrap 3rd party exceptions, and I add instances in a memory cache server-side. The client then gets the exception by doing:

```
var resp = await client.GetAsync("url");
```

If I do the following:

```
throw await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<InternalException>(ct);
```

I get an exception `The member ClassName could not be found`. So I tried:

```
var str = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var ex = Convert.DeserializeObject<InternalException>(str);
throw ex;
```

`str` is the correctly deserialized exception. However, when I do the above, `ex` is a completely new exception and its message is `An exception of type "InternalException" was thrown`.

Why is a new exception being created and how do I actually deserialize the original exception and throw it successfully?

Note: This is an internal api and client and I do need to return exceptions to the client.

Comment: @stuartd It does have a property `InnerException` because it inherits from `Exception`. And when I create an instance and set the inner exception, this inner exception might be a complex exception with further inner exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your streaming constructor, you need to invoke the base constructor:

```
[Serializable]
public class InternalException : Exception, ISerializable
{ 
    protected InternalException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
        : base(info, context) // ADD THIS
    {  }

    // Remainder unchanged
```

You need to do this because the base streaming constructor is what deserializes the base exception's fields -- including the message field.  Json.NET uses the streaming constructor because, as explained in the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#ISerializable),

> `ISerializable`
>
> Types that implement `ISerializable` and are marked with `SerializableAttribute` are serialized as JSON objects. When serializing, only the values returned from ISerializable.GetObjectData are used; members on the type are ignored. **When deserializing, the constructor with a SerializationInfo and StreamingContext is called, passing the JSON object's values.**

Notes:

- `resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<InternalException>(ct)` likely does not work because MSFT's newest built-in JSON serializer, [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json), does not support serializing of exceptions as of .NET 7.  See *[Why does System.Text.Json throw a `NotSupportedException` for `System.IntPtr` when I'm not using `System.IntPtr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71132371/3744182)* for details.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6N0tXa).