# System.Text.Json Serialization NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I have a class `EventClass` that inherits from an abstract class as shown below.

```
    public abstract class BaseClass : MessageClass
{
    protected BaseClass(string type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
    }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MessageClass
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
}

public class EventClass
{
    public static string StreamName = "name";
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public Guid AggregateId{ get; set; }
    public string AggregateType { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public BaseClass EventData { get; set; }
}
```

`EventData` here will be any object that inherits from `BaseClass`. For instance:

```
 public class EventChild : BaseClass
{
    public EventChild() : base(nameof(EventChild))
    {
        
    }
    public string FullName {get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to serialize an event of type `EventClass` and append to a stream of EventStoreDb with `AppendToStreamAsync`, then deserialize back to the event after calling `ReadStreamAsync`:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes<EventClass>(@event);
EventClass eventObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EventClass>(item.Event.Data.Span);
```

However, I keep getting a serialization error below in both cases:

```
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Reflection.MethodBase' instances is not supported. Path: $.TargetSite.
   ---> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Reflection.MethodBase' instances is not supported.
     at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.UnsupportedTypeConverter`1.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
     at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
     at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
     at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
     at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
     at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(WriteStack& state, NotSupportedException ex)
     at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) 3
     at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.SerializeAsync(Stream utf8Json, T rootValue, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object rootValueBoxed)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) 2
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware:
    Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
```

Does anyone previously experienced this or have a clue what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You can (I have just) simplify this to "I have made something that can't be serialized" - where you are going to put it is beside the point. Does the data you are attempting to serialize have a `delegate` or a `Func` etc in it, or a child object?

Comment: A object of a class that inherits an abstract class...

Comment: The bottom line is you are trying to serialize something that System.Text.Json does not support serializing. To get anywhere useful, we need to switch from you making the world guess, to you showing what your data structure looks like (with as much detail as you can provide), what you are hoping it will serialize to, and generally providing more context.

Comment: I have provided some more context in the question.

Comment: I suspect that what is actually happening is that, somewhere in your code, you are catching an exception and trying to return the exception -- and, unfortunately, System.Text.Json cannot serialize the `Exception` class.  See [Why does System.Text.Json throw a `NotSupportedException` for `System.IntPtr` when I'm not using `System.IntPtr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71132371/3744182).  In that case an `IntPtr` was the first non-serializable property of `Exception` that was encountered but `Exception` also has the `TargetSite` property which is declared as `MethodBase`.

Comment: As an aside, mutable static fields like `public static string StreamName = "name";` are liable to cause all sorts of problems in multithreaded scenarios.  If that field is actually never mutated, you should make it `readonly` or `const`.

Comment: To successfully round-trip properties such as `public BaseClass EventData { get; set; }` with polymorphic values using System.Text.Json, see [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182).

Comment: Where you eventually aim to go is not relevant to the question - focus on the serialization bit only. Having said that, I'd advise against having deep type hierarchies for Event Data like that - keep the metadata in the Metadata field, and only keep actual relevant event-specific information in the Data. You are not designing an uber envelope for the ultimate messaging system. You have not shown `MessageClass` yet - it's likely to contain something that's not serializing well. But the bottom line is you should start from a small basic event payload and work up from that

Comment: Thanks@dbc your comments pointed me in the right direction.